# Unable to update AAD application setting through graph api explorer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I tried to update Azure AAD application setting through Graph explorer  but getting error as `MethodNotAllowed`

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

[image]

I even tried samples given by below Microsoft official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but still getting same issue.

I tried to call **GraphAPI** `UpdateAsync()` from C# code, but got error

> Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request

While initiating request, I have specified PATCH even then getting issues.

**Update:**

I tried by passing `AAD App object_id`  in `Graph API url` as below but still getting issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API does not support `$filter` expression.

If you want to fetch the application by ID, you need to use [list applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API with `$filter` query expression.

For example:

[image]

Then, use [update application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to update it:

[image]

Comment: @Jak Jia I tried all steps mentioned by you , I passed AAD app objectID in url, but still facing same MethodNotAllowed issue.

Comment: @John Any screenshot?

Comment: I tried again, and everything works fine here. Notice that, you can only update application with `PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{object_id}`

Comment: @Jak Jia, I have updated screenshot in question.Kindly take a look and suggest any solution for the issue. I have passed objectID in the url and using PATCH

Comment: @John Sorry for not responding in time, I was on holiday. Have you checked your permission? I cannot reproduce your issue